# AutoCompleteTextView adapter not displaying dropdown?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, autocompletetextview

Here is my onCreate method:

```
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.getData() == null)
        intent.setData(Formulas.CONTENT_URI);

    AutoCompleteTextView searchBar = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(getIntent().getData(),new String[] { Formulas.TITLE }, null, null, null);
    SimpleCursorAdapter searchAdapter = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, c, 
                new String[] { Formulas.TITLE } , new int[] { android.R.id.text1} );
    searchBar.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
}
```

I did input some sample data in my databaseopenhelper:

```
        @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE formula ( \n" +
                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, \n" +
                "title TEXT NOT NULL, \n" +
                "formula TEXT NOT NULL \n" +
                ");");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO formula VALUES ( \n" +
                "null, \"Pythagorean theorium\", \"a^2+b^2=c^2\" \n" +
                "); ");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO formula VALUES ( \n" +
                "null, \"Perimeter of a square\", \"l^2 * w^2\" \n" +
                "); ");
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO formula VALUES ( \n" +
                "null, \"Area of a square\", \"l^4\" \n" +
                "); ");
    }
```

The problem is where I set the adapter to the `AutoCompleteTextView`, I expect the values that I inserted using the `SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(String)` method. But nothing is there? The dropdown box doesn't even show up? I used debugging and found that the `Cursor` was not null and neither was the adapter or `AutoCompleteTextView`? What could be the problem? I already defined my own contentprovider.

Comment: why do you have `\n`s and stuff in your sql queries? Also, what's the error? Post the stack trace or error message

Comment: @Falmarri Sorry I wasn't clear. I used an ORM to create the database create methods and I just pasted it into eclipse and it auto formatted. There is no error. When I set the adapter for the AutoCompleteTextView, I expect "Area of a square" "Pythagorean theorium" and "perimeter of a square" to be displayed in the dropdown box. But nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query returned nothing because the content uri was faulty and completely my fault. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541894/unknown-url-contentunknown-url-content-com-mohit-provider-formulaprovider-formu)  is the relavent thread.