# Unknown URL content:Unknown URL content:\com.mohit.provider.FormulaProvider\formulas

Tags: java, android, uri, android-contentprovider

I get this error everytime I try to use my content provider to insert a URI. Here is the method:

```
private void sample() {
    ContentValues values;

    values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Formulas.TITLE, "Formula1");
    values.put(Formulas.FORMULA, "someformula");
    getContentResolver().insert(getIntent().getData(), values);

    values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Formulas.TITLE, "Formula2");
    values.put(Formulas.FORMULA, "someformula");
    getContentResolver().insert(getIntent().getData(), values);

    values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Formulas.TITLE, "Formula3");
    values.put(Formulas.FORMULA, "someformula");
    getContentResolver().insert(getIntent().getData(), values);
}
```

Previously I set the Intent data here:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.getData() == null)
    intent.setData(Formulas.CONTENT_URI);
```

Here is my content URI and authority:

```
public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.mohit.provider.FormulaProvider";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content:\\" + AUTHORITY + "\formulas");
```

Here is the provider tag:

```
<provider android:name="com.mohit.provider.FormulaProvider" 
        android:authorities="com.mohit.provider.FormulaProvider" />
```

And finally the Logcat log:

```
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mohit.gformula.activities/com.mohit.gformula.activities.FormulasList}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content:\\com.mohit.provider.FormulaProvider\formulas
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content:\\com.mohit.provider.FormulaProvider\formulas
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:583)
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at com.mohit.gformula.activities.FormulasList.sample(FormulasList.java:38)
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at com.mohit.gformula.activities.FormulasList.onCreate(FormulasList.java:23)
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-22 14:42:07.362: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

backslashes \ look strange in a URI, try // resp. /

Comment: That was completely my fault. I forgot about the Unix structure.